Add extra column for percent
I loaded a table which has columns name of issue, date of issue and weeks_in_work for each issue.
I have visualized table with weeks_in_work and amount of issues
Something like this

I want to add another column
ratio of the number of issues for each week to the total number with accumulation

I created a measure
AmountOfIssuesPerWeek = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Query'[issue_name]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Query', 'Query'[weeks_in_work])
)

And
AllIssues = COUNT('Query'[issue_name])

Then
Percent = 
DIVIDE([AmountOfIssuesPerWeek ], [AllIssues]) * 100

As you can see I got strange numbers. The problem is I have a filter on date, so I can't create a table
Is is it possible to make this using measures and with working filter?
Help me please :)
UPD: Attached the model and screen how it looks like in PBI

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epF19AY6XVc6wFlS-3hoFyB296rYxQTJ/view?usp=drivesdk

Can you please share your model ? How are you using the date slicer ?

@AmiraBedhiafi done

I can't open the link.
So I created the similar data. I used sum, you can try to change sum to count
count of s.issue_name = sum('Table'[Issue_name])

PROPORTION =
[count of s.issue_name]
    / CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Issue_name] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )

P2 =
VAR _PROPORTION = [PROPORTION]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [PROPORTION],
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table'[weeks_in_work] ),
            'Table'[weeks_in_work] <= MAX ( 'Table'[weeks_in_work] )
        )
    )



it says Calculation error in measure 'Query'[Proportion] the function SUM cannot work with values type of String. Issue_name is string type. I also attached screen of example how data looks like in a table and new link. Please try this one https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epF19AY6XVc6wFlS-3hoFyB296rYxQTJ/view?usp=drivesdk

It's very difficult for me to open google drive.You can  try to change SUM to COUNT
